# How to loop for minimum RMSE values and use "apply" for forecasting in each column

Tags: r

Could anyone provides me guidance on how to use for loop to look up minimum RMSE value and use "apply function" for forecasting in each column? Here is the dataset.

T   6753    6763    6803    6806    6777    6799    6809    6832    6838    6831    6838    6807    6782    6809    6785    6766    6788    6704    6656    7093    7091    7100    7074    7047    7063    7070    7068    7054    7056    7067    7040    7027    7032    7055    7058    7051    7074    7109    7103    7127    7121    7111    7123    7147    7119    7106    7103    7091    7097    7103    7086    7099    7094    7139    7186    7198    7248    7274    7319    7329    7384    7410    7479

C   2307    2296    2297    2287    2273    2259    2246    2230    2215    2194    2175    2110    2098    2074    2070    2107    2117    2128    2106    1687    1674    1664    1638    1641    1672    1679    1677    1675    1681    1675    1665    1697    1694    1693    1693    1691    1703    1706    1700    1695    1698    1712    1688    1701    1693    1674    1690    1688    1710    1711    1692    1688    1700    1684    1755    1744    1764    1762    1753    1753    1768    1763    1788

I have a total of 2 columns that I need to forecast in R. I plan to use "Holt" to forecast future values. One of the variables in Holt is to input beta. I don't know how to write a function to assign beta to each column.

Following is how I calculate RMSE value. It is easy if I only have one column. But now I have 2 or more columns.

```
beta<-seq(.05,.9,by=0.001)
RMSE<-NULL
for (i in seq_along(beta)){
  fit<-holt(cretrain, beta=beta[i],h = length(cretest))
  RMSE[i]<-accuracy(fit,cretest)[2,2]
}

beta.fit<-data_frame(beta,RMSE)
beta.min<-filter(beta.fit,RMSE==min(RMSE))
```

Here is how I use apply for forecasting. Ideally, I want beta to base off the values that coming out of the fist chunk of codes.

```
list<-apply(df,2,function(x)holt(ts(x,start = c(2015,1),end = c(2020,1),frequency = 12),h=2,beta=.5))
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can loop over the columns with `lapply`, then loop over the 'beta' values, apply the `holt`, `rbind` the  `accuracy` measures for each 'beta' ('beta.fit'), `subset` the rows where the 'RMSE' is `min`imum.  This returns the subset for each column of the dataset

```
beta <- seq(.05, .9,by=0.001)
out <- lapply(df, function(x) {
         beta.fit <- do.call(rbind, lapply(beta, function(b) {
             fit <- holt(x, beta = b, h = length(x))
             print(head(fit$mean))
               data.frame(beta = b, RMSE =  accuracy(fit, x)[2,2])
             }))
       subset(beta.fit, RMSE == min(RMSE))
     })
```

Comment: Thanks Akrun! I ran your codes, but the min RMSE value is different than I ran it individually. Was the beta the minimum value in your code? Sorry, I am not a experienced coder. Maybe I am wrong.

Comment: @Ivan does it depends on any random component.  Here, I am using the same code as in the `for` loop

Comment: I think what I don't understand is how to output the forecasts. I ran subset, it does show the correct beta. I think I don't know how to look at all the values. Any suggestions on how to do this? When I ran "fit", it only shows the last value. Thanks.

Comment: @Ivan the best option to check is `str` i.e. it gives the structure of the forecast object i.e. you can do `str(fit)` and then you would know which element you can extract.  Mostly, it is a list and list element can be extracted with `$` or `[[`

Comment: I looked for mean using $. Wouldn't it generate two different means for two columns instead of one? I only see one. Thanks

Comment: @Ivan can you please. update your post with a small example for `df` so that I can test it

Comment: @Ivan nevermind.  If you use `fcast <- holt(airmiles);` and `str(fcast)`, you wll find the `mean`

Comment: @Iivan for each model build, there will be a `mean` `fcast$mean`.  In the loop.  If you print, you will find that.  I added the print statemnt iin the post

Comment: I just updated the data set. It is getting really close to the solution. Hope it helps with the testing. Thanks again

Comment: @Ivan Please use `dput` so that i get the strructure of your 'df'

Comment: To clarify my question, I try to calculate two forecasts based on these two data sets with betas that minimize RMSE.

Comment: @Ivan Here, in the loop, we are only doing this on a single dataset columns.  If you are trying to compare based on two dataset corresponding columns, then you may need `Map`

Comment: @Ivan That I would post as a separate question because it needs more changes in the code

Comment: just posted "How to "map" or "apply" to get the best beta from each column"